# why do you think microsoft hasn't implemented asp-classic as another language in .net

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, frameworks, migration

a couple of days ago I had this idea, why not implementing asp-classic as another language in .net...

it would have helped lots of people to migrate to the new platform...

I mean there's IronRuby, IronPython, etc...

It sounded to me like a great idea... but, come on, I'm no genius, there must be some reason why they haven't done so...

I'm just curious about it...

Comment: If you really want to go down this path maybe you could beg Joel Spolsky to sell you licenses to use Wasabi. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Microsoft has given up on backwards compatibility of their API's. I guess they figured that using the maintenance cost for new development was a better investment.

Sometimes I agree, sometimes I disagree with their new view...

Now so you don't think its just me projecting my thought on microsoft here you have some references:

- [Joel's an article about it](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/APIWar.html)

> The first big win was making Visual Basic.NET not backwards-compatible with VB 6.0. This was literally the first time in living memory that when you bought an upgrade to a Microsoft product, your old data (i.e. the code you had written in VB6) could not be imported perfectly and silently. It was the first time a Microsoft upgrade did not respect the work that users did using the previous version of a product.
>
> ...
>
> With this major victory under their belts, the MSDN Magazine Camp took over. Suddenly it was OK to change things. IIS 6.0 came out with a different threading model that broke some old applications. I was shocked to discover that our customers with Windows Server 2003 were having trouble running FogBugz. Then .NET 1.1 was not perfectly backwards compatible with 1.0. And now that the cat was out of the bag, the OS team got into the spirit and decided that instead of adding features to the Windows API, they were going to completely replace it.

Answer (score 4):

Primarily because asp-classis is not a langauge.  Its a very small framework of COM objects.

The builtin languages for use in ASP are VBScript and Javascript.  I can't see why anyone would want to use "VBScript.NET" and "JScript.NET" does exist although its a bit of dogs dinner.

You can take a ASPX page with VB.NET can code isn ASPEsq manner if you like.